# Qt- QNetworkReply delete operator- Runtime Crash

Tags: qt, network-programming, qnetworkaccessmanager

In my Qt application, I am using QNetworkAccessManager in a Thread so as to keep my main thread free to do its task. For every get operation that I do, I am storing the QNetworkReply* in a list and upon a response, I retrieve it from my list, delete the entry in the list and call deleteLater() on the QNetworkReply* object. However, after a couple of request/responses here is the crash i get in runtime:

The code that I used is:

```
void NetworkManager::responseFromServer(QNetworkReply* pReply)
{

  // Retrieve the TileRequestMessage.
  QImage *pImage = imageMapper.value(pReply);
  // Get the bytes from the response.
  QByteArray byteArray = pReply->readAll();
  // Load the QImage with the data.
  bool loaded = pImage->loadFromData(byteArray);

  // Remove the request from book-keeping.
  imageMapper.remove(mapIterator.key());
  pReply->deleteLater();
  return;
}
```

where pImage is a pointer to a object of type QImage. The Object is created in advance and its pointer mapped to a QNetworkReply* is stored in a QMap.

The error I get is:

> Stopped at 0x637837aa (operator delete) in thread 1 (missing debug information). 
>   sException at 0x637837aa, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0xffffffffcdcdcdc1, 
>   flags=0x0

The call stack is:

> 0  operator delete MSVCR90D    0   0x637837aa
>   1   QList::node_destruct  qlist.h 418 0x64071704
>   2   QList::free   qlist.h 744 0x6407153b
>   3   QList::~QList   qlist.h 718 0x64070b1f
>   4   QQueue::~QQueue qqueue.h    58  0x6407076f
>   5   QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::handleNotifications   qnetworkreplyimpl.cpp   358 0x6406c99d
>   6   QNetworkReplyImpl::event    qnetworkreplyimpl.cpp   868 0x6406e646
>   7   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    4445    0x6507153e
>   8   QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3845    0x6506f1ba
>   9   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    732 0x671c2fb1
>   10  QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  215 0x671c8159
>   11  QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents   qcoreapplication.cpp    1373    0x671c3f0b
>   12  qt_internal_proc    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    506 0x67206bf9
>   13  IsThreadDesktopComposited   USER32  0   0x77bb86ef
>   14  IsThreadDesktopComposited   USER32  0   0x77bb8876
>   15  IsThreadDesktopComposited   USER32  0   0x77bb89b5
>   16  DispatchMessageW    USER32  0   0x77bb8e9c
>   17  QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    807 0x67207b96
>   18  QEventLoop::processEvents   qeventloop.cpp  150 0x671c0abe
>   19  QEventLoop::exec    qeventloop.cpp  201 0x671c0bf0
>   20  QThread::exec   qthread.cpp 490 0x670643d6
>   21  DispatcherThread::run   DispatcherThread.cpp    226 0x1001031a
>   22  QThreadPrivate::start   qthread_win.cpp 317 0x6706852f
>   23  beginthreadex   MSVCR90D    0   0x636edff3
>   24  beginthreadex   MSVCR90D    0   0x636edf89
>   25  BaseThreadInitThunk kernel32    0   0x77191194
>   26  RtlInitializeExceptionChain ntdll   0   0x77ccb429
>   27  RtlInitializeExceptionChain ntdll   0   0x77ccb3fc

I am using msvc to compile my Qt code. Any heads-up on what the problem might be ??

Thanks,

Vishnu.

Comment: Some code on how you manage (and delete) the QNetworkReply objects might help.

Comment: modified the question to add the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your actual code and based on your error description, it could be possible that you are deleting the QNetworkReply before it has emitted the `finished` signal. So after the deletion when new data becomes available - QNetworkReply emits the `readyRead` signal which is when it would be trying to access the already deleted entry and hence the "read access violation" errors.

Comment: That's the exact reason I am calling the deleteLater() method in my slot. Also, I am wondering how can QNetworkReply emit readyRead signal after the QNetworkReply object has been deleted.

Comment: Also, on further investigation, i found that sometimes the finished() signal of QNetworkReply* fires after the finished() signal of QNetworkAccessManager (where the QNetworkReply*) is deleted, and thus sender in my slot connected to finished() signal in QNetworkReply* is marked 0x00. If that is the case, where should i delete my QNetworkReply* object ???

Comment: For your first comment, QNetworkReply object is not created by you and it is obtained in the `QNetworkAccessManager::get`. So this means you do not have control on the QNetworkReply object thus created and hence it can emit the `readyRead` signal whenever there is new data available to read.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation of the `QNetworkAccessManager::finished` slot[link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished). It is clearly mentioned not to perform `delete` of the QNetworkReply object in this slot. So may be you can try deleting the QNetworkReply object using deleteLater() at the end of all network accesses.

Comment: Before performing the `deleteLater()` on the QNetworkReply object, you can check if it has finished the processing using `isFinished()`.

Comment: @Purnima: I apologize if I sounded like i am using delete operator itself. I am using deleteLater() to delete the instance of QNetworkReply objects. Is there a way for me to stop all the activity of QNetworkReply* once I call my deleteLater () ??

Comment: You can try calling `QNetworkReply::abort()` on the QNetworkReply objects and then issue the `deleteLater()` operation. Please refer to the [abort](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html#abort) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did see a crash after the such a change. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Since you use deleteLater() you do not know when the delete will take place and thus when the pointer QNetworkReply* may be invalid in your list.

Thus, maybe try wrapping your pointer in a guared pointer ([QPointer](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qpointer.html)) and then just remove it from the list if it deleted/null. If it's still a valid pointer you call deleteLater();